# Iterate check boxes - pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

I have a file with changing numbers (every time I call a QGIS plugin ):

```
0
8
7
```

And I have 9 check boxes (self.t0, self.t1, ..., self.t8)

With the content of the file I want to set the boxes checked:

I tried this:

```
class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.set_prefs.clicked.connect(self.preferences)
        self.cancel.clicked.connect(self.closePlugin)

        with open(r'C:\\path\\checklist.txt', "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                checkboxname = "t" + str(line)
                self.checkboxname.setChecked(True)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'mask_n_functions' object has no attribute 'checkboxname'
```

How can I iterate over check boxes?

Do I have to use a group box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function. The style you are using, works in PHP, not in Python.

So, use something like below in place of your last line mentioned in the question.

```
checkbox = getattr(self, checkboxname)
checkbox.setChecked(True)
```

Comment: Thank you. It only works when I remove all whitespaces from the checkboxname string with `checkboxstring = "t" + str(line)` and `checkboxname = checkboxstring.strip()`. There were whitespaces in the string when reading it from the file (not seen in the open text file).

Comment: Yes, the attribute name has to be correct, whitespaces will be an issue.